# How can I refresh a dropdown if a new value is added to an input in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I hope you can help me understand what I'm doing wrong. I'm creating a quiz application and I'm currently working on editing the questions for the quiz. I would like to pull the possible answers initially from the database, and then whenever an answer was edited, refresh the dropdown with the current options. I'm stuck at the stage where the dropdown is not refreshing after updating the options. Is there a way to achieve this?

here is my HTML (at the moment I'm only tracking change from Answer 1):

```html
 <main role="main" class="col-md-9 ml-sm-auto col-lg-10 px-4">
            <div class="inner-adjust">

                <div class="pt-3 pb-2 mb-3 border-bottom">
                    <h1 class="h2">Quiz</h1>
                    <!--input type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchTerm" placeholder="Search by Course Name" -->
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <form (ngSubmit)="submitChanges()">
                        <div class="form-group p-2" *ngIf="question as quesion">
                            <label for="question">Question</label>
                            <input type="text" name="question" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="ques"
                                placeholder={{question.question}}>
                            <label for="answer11">Answer 1</label>
                            <input type="text" min="0" step="0.1" name="answer11" class="form-control"
                                [(ngModel)]="answer1" placeholder={{question.answer1}}
                                (change)="updateDropDownValues(answer1)">
                            <label for="answer2">Answer 2</label>
                            <input type="text" min="0" step="0.1" name="answer2" class="form-control"
                                [(ngModel)]="answer2" placeholder={{question.answer2}}>
                            <label for="answer3">Answer 3</label>
                            <input type="text" min="0" step="0.1" name="answer3" class="form-control"
                                [(ngModel)]="answer3" placeholder={{question.answer3}}>
                            <label for="answer4">Answer 4</label>
                            <input type="text" min="0" step="0.1" name="answer4" class="form-control"
                                [(ngModel)]="answer4" placeholder={{question.answer4}}>
                            <form>
                                <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                                    <label for="solution">Solution </label>
                                    <select [(ngModel)]="solution" name="solution">
                                        <option *ngFor="let solution of possibleAnswers" [ngValue]="solution"
                                            [ngSelected]="question.solution">
                                            {{solution}}
                                        </option>,
                                    </select>
                                </mat-form-field>
                                <p></p>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group p-2">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
```

And here is my .ts:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Course } from 'src/app/course';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';
import { Question } from 'src/app/question'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit-question',
  templateUrl: './edit-question.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edit-question.component.css']
})
export class EditQuestionComponent implements OnInit {
  localAuthService: AuthService;
  courseName: string;
  questionID: number;
  course: Course;
  question: Question;
  ques: string;
  answer1: string;
  answer2 : string;
  answer3: string;
  solution: string;
  possibleAnswers : string[];

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase, private router: Router, private authService: AuthService, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { 
    this.localAuthService = authService;
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(event => {
      this.courseName = event.courseName;
      this.questionID = event.id;
      this.db.object('/Courses/' + this.courseName).valueChanges().subscribe(course => {
        this.course = course as Course;
        this.question = this.course.questions[this.questionID]
        this.possibleAnswers = new Array;
        this.possibleAnswers.push(this.question.answer1);
        this.possibleAnswers.push(this.question.answer2);
        this.possibleAnswers.push(this.question.answer3);
        this.possibleAnswers.push(this.question.answer4);
      });
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    
  }

  submitChanges() {

  }

  updateDropDownValues(value: any ){
    this.possibleAnswers.push(value);
  }


}
```

I appreciate any help!
Thank you!

Comment: I would suggest that you look for blur event on the input field and check if the form got dirty, if the form is dirty then update the DB with the new fields and once the update is completed and you get a successful response, reassign the values of answer1, 2,3 and 4 to the values received from the response.

Answer (score 0):

Implement onChange event in your input (triggering change as you type:

`<input [(ngModel)]="your model" type="text (change)="onChangeEvent($event)">`

Then finally, in your method:

`onChangeEvent() { //Here you update the value of your drop down from your input }`